# If $p>0$, then $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}=0$ using squeeze theorem for sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-explanation

> If $p>0$, then $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}=0\;.$

Rudin suggests in his [*Principle of Mathematical Analysis*](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/principles-of-mathematical-analysis) to take  $$n> (\frac{1}{\epsilon})^\frac{1}{p}$$ using the Archimedean property of the real number system.

This is under the assumption that we will compute the limit of the sequence based on the fact: If $\ 0 \leq x_n \leq s_n$ for $\ n \geq N$, where N is some fixed number, and if $\ s_n \rightarrow 0$, then $\ x_n \rightarrow 0.$

I don't really understand this proof, but I could try it a different way:

Letting $\ x_n = \frac{1}{n^p}$ and taking $\ s_n$ to be $\ \frac{1}{n}$, then we know that $\ x_n \leq s_n $ because $\ p>0 $. But since $ s_n = \frac{1}{n}$ goes to $0$ as $n$ approaches infinity, we know from $0 \leq x_n \leq s_n$ that $ x_n = \frac{1}{n^p}$ will also go to $0$ as $n$ approaches infinity.

Is this a valid approach?

Comment: You are assuming $p\ge1$,

Comment: I see what you mean. In the case p was infinitesimal, what happens to Rudin's suggested inequality?

Comment: There are no "infinitesimals" in Rudin's book.

Comment: Another way : If $1/n^p$ does not converge to $0$ then there exists $ r>0$ such that    $1/n^p>r$ for  infinitely many $n $. But then the real number $r^{1/p}$ is greater than infinitely many members of $\Bbb N.$

Comment: There are o infinitesimals in $\Bbb R $. This follow from the definition of $\Bbb R.$ Most references to infinitesimals are just short-hand .

Answer (score 3):

What you mentioned is Theorem 3.20 in Rudin's book (page 57).

If one takes $n>(1/\varepsilon)^{1/p}$, then it follows that $n^p>1/\varepsilon$ (because $p>0$) and thus $\displaystyle\frac{1}{n^p}<\varepsilon$. In particular, this argument shows that if one takes a positive integer $N>(1/\varepsilon)^{1/p}$, existence given by the archimedean property, then for any integer $n>N$, one has
$$
n^p>N^p>1/\varepsilon,
$$
equivalently,
$$
\left|\frac{1}{n^p}-0\right|<\varepsilon\;.
$$
This implies by definition of limits that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}=0$.

---

Rudin indeed says before the theorem that the squeeze theorem will be used:

> [image]

But should not take his words too literally ("The proofs will *all* be ..."). If you take look at the (one line) proof of (e), all he says is "Take $\alpha=0$ in (d)", which is not quite using the squeeze theorem *per se*.

Answer (score 0):

Is Rudin serious? Do you acutally prove

> If $p>0$, then $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}=0\;.$

using the squeeze theorem?

Well, he might have been teasing the student a bit with that one. The most elementary/first principle thing we learn is that

$\tag 1 \displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$

and that it follows from the Archimedean property. So one 'heartbeat away' we demonstrate that

$\tag 2 \displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^p}=0$

once again using the Archimedean property.

So how does Rudin justify bringing out the squeeze theorem here?

Well, just set $x_n = \frac{1}{n^p}$ and $s_n = \frac{1}{n^p}$ (you've seen in Rudin's proof that that $s_n$ converges to $0$).

I think Rudin would have made a great lawyer!